# How should I use Cognito User Pool API inside Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have a Cognito User Pool, I know it can trigger Lambda functions but I need the inverse. I need to create user, and check if user with preferred username or alias exists in my lambda functions. Should I do it using Cognito REST API, if how is authentication performed? I could not find any similar implementations or examples in the web, I wonder if I am in the wrong way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The AWS SDK is available to use in your Lambda function. You would use the Cognito features in the SDK to perform the actions you have described.